# Why glDrawElements draws nothing?

Tags: opengl

I tried to implement indexed draw, but when I call I got nothing on screen. Even more strange that I wasn't get any error when call it and buffer variables packed right.

There my constructor:

```
Mesh::Mesh(Shader &shader, std::vector<GLuint>* indices, std::vector<VertexData>* vertices) {
shaderProgram = &shader;
_meshLenght = (GLsizei) indices->size();
_indices = indices;

glGenBuffers(1, &_ebo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices->size(), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//create one here
glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArray(_vao);


std::vector<glm::vec3> positions {};
std::vector<glm::vec3> normals {};
std::vector<glm::vec2> texture {};

for (size_t i = 0; i < vertices->size(); ++i) {
    positions.push_back(vertices->at(i).positions);
    normals.push_back(vertices->at(i).normals);
    texture.push_back(vertices->at(i).texCoords);
}

glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3)*(positions.size()+normals.size()), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(glm::vec3)*positions.size(), positions.data());
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3)*positions.size(), sizeof(glm::vec3)*normals.size(), normals.data());

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<const void*>((sizeof(glm::vec3) * positions.size())));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And there my draw code:

```
void Mesh::Draw() {
glBindVertexArray(_vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ebo);
if (_ebo==0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _meshLenght);
else {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _meshLenght, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Also show my vertices info screenshot:
 [image]

And if you need have apitrace trace file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dWIpzqq91mQXVIeHhTOHFhRkU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices->size(), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This is wrong. `indices->size()` is the number of indices you have, but yet we see from the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) (my emphasis):

> *size* Specifies the **size in bytes** of the buffer object's new data store.

Use `indices->size() * sizeof (GLuint)` instead.

You should also be using `&indices[0]` for the *data* parameter instead of just `indices`.

Comment: Oh thank you for answer for such dumb question. But I recommend to use indices->data because indices is vector.